# Using resample() and apply() for filling only consecutive periods for an specific date range... any idea?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find all missing consecutive periods into a dataframe with a date index,  I am using minute format.  This is my dataframe:

```
         date         Col1         Col2       Col3
2020-03-19 17:29:00 -2.245783   -0.400823   -1.480578
2020-03-19 17:30:00 2.079340    -0.401838   -0.203679
2020-03-20 09:00:00 -0.525591   0.369816    1.268433
2020-03-20 09:02:00 1.444231    -0.674311   0.595214
2020-03-20 09:03:00 -0.582655   -0.218627   1.755375
2020-03-20 09:04:00 -0.937102   0.078935    -0.516713
2020-03-20 09:05:00 0.128797    -1.201757   -1.478310
```

You can see that there is no “09:01” minute.  If I resample this by minute I obtain the following:

```
df = df.resample(rule="min").mean()

         date         Col1         Col2       Col3
2020-03-19 17:29:00 -2.245783   -0.400823   -1.480578
2020-03-19 17:30:00 2.079340    -0.401838   -0.203679
2020-03-19 17:31:00 NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-19 17:32:00 NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-19 17:33:00 NaN NaN NaN
………………………………………………………………………..
2020-03-20 08:59:00 NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-20 09:00:00 -0.525591   0.369816    1.268433
2020-03-20 09:01:00 NaN NaN NaN
2020-03-20 09:02:00 1.444231    -0.674311   0.595214
```

Of course, I will “fill” it with my missing ‘09:01’ minutes, but… I am obtaining also lots of undesired “minutes”
How can I apply any kind of function to this resample to obtain “only” missing data between my consecutive rows, only the ’09:01’ minute or other within a timetable (not 24x7)?

Many thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter with [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) for business hours and [`DatetimeIndex.weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) for business days after you call `resample`:

```
df = df.resample(rule="min").mean()

df = df.between_time("9:00", "17:30")         # BUSINESS HOURS FILTER
df = df[df.index.weekday.isin(range(0,5))]    # BUSINESS DAY FILTER

df    
#                          Col1      Col2      Col3
# date
# 2020-03-19 17:29:00 -2.245783 -0.400823 -1.480578
# 2020-03-19 17:30:00  2.079340 -0.401838 -0.203679
# 2020-03-20 09:00:00 -0.525591  0.369816  1.268433
# 2020-03-20 09:01:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
# 2020-03-20 09:02:00  1.444231 -0.674311  0.595214
# 2020-03-20 09:03:00 -0.582655 -0.218627  1.755375
# 2020-03-20 09:04:00 -0.937102  0.078935 -0.516713
# 2020-03-20 09:05:00  0.128797 -1.201757 -1.478310
```

Comment: Many thanks, very smart and simple solution.  I thought also to use weekday() to select only Mo-Fri and holidays() from pandas_market_calendars...  with all those combinations I can get a right business days and hours dataframe...  ;)

Comment: See edit with index filter for business days using `DatetimeIndex.weekday`.